# VB.Net - Add Handler to object of unknown type?

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, events, types

I am trying to create a Sub that can take an object and add a load of event handlers for it, but the object can be any one of N types that all have these events. How can I do this? If I just have it as an Object as below AddHandler complains that the event does not exist for Object.

Can this be done?

```
Sub addHandlers(ByVal inputObject as object)
    AddHandler inputObject.MouseDown, AddressOf HandleClick
    AddHandler inputObject.MouseUp, AddressOf HandleMouseUp
End Sub
```

**EDIT:** Each of these objects is an instance of a class that inherits a different class (usually a control) that already has these events.

Thanks for any help,
Sam.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You probably just want to make `inputObject` a type that has all of these members. For example, if your using WinForms, it would be Control:

```
Sub addHandlers(ByVal inputObject As Control)
    AddHandler inputObject.MouseDown, AddressOf HandleClick
    AddHandler inputObject.MouseUp, AddressOf HandleMouseUp
End Sub
```

Or if WPF, use `UIElement`:

```
Sub addHandlers(ByVal inputObject As UIElement)
    AddHandler inputObject.MouseDown, AddressOf HandleClick
    AddHandler inputObject.MouseUp, AddressOf HandleMouseUp
End Sub
```

Now any control that is of that type can be passed into `addHandlers`.

**EDIT**:

If there is no common type between all of them, you *could* use reflection:

```
Sub addHandlers(ByVal inputObject As Object)
    Dim type = inputObject.GetType()
    Dim handleClickDel = New MouseEventHandler(AddressOf HandleClick)
    Dim handleUpDel = New MouseEventHandler(AddressOf HandleMouseUp)
    type.GetEvent("MouseDown").AddEventHandler(inputObject, handleClickDel)
    type.GetEvent("MouseUp").AddEventHandler(inputObject, handleUpDel)
End Sub
```

The delegate type must still match though. This feels a bit clunky to me, though. If possible, try creating different overloads for `addHandlers` as needed, and using base types to avoid creating many of them. If own the code of the types that can be passed in as `inputOjbect`, use an interface.

Comment: I thought of that but they do not all share an inherited type.

Comment: @SeriousSamP I added some additional details.

Comment: +1: The reflection method is a great approach. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

If they don't all inherit from the same type, you will likely need to implement an interface on each of them in order to give them commonality.

and then use the interface definition of an event and implement it on the existing events for each object.

Interface:

```
Public Interface MyInterface
      Event PropertyChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
End Interface
```

Object with the event:

```
Public WhateverClass
    Implements MyInterface

    Public Event PropertyChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Implements IMyInterface

End Class
```

Class that needs the handler:

```
  Public Class SomeOtherClass
      Public Sub AddHandlers (ByVal inputObject as MyInterface)
         AddHandler inputObject.PropertyChanged, AddressOf PropertyChanged

      End Sub

      Public Sub PropertyChanged(ByVal sender as Object, ByVal e as EventArgs)
        'Do Stuff
      End Sub
  End Class
```

Comment: I cannot use the interface approach because the events are already declared in the parent classes. See edit to question.